# How to automate software feature test coverage via tagging?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, tag

We are considering map software features against their respective automated test case to assess test coverage.

1. The initial step is manually record all available software features
2. The second step is manually compare features against their respective test case, if all software feature have at least one automated test case, we will have a 100% test coverage.

But the problem is long-term maintenance, it is not economical to go through this process manually.

We are thinking of introducing feature-tagging, with each feature, a unique tag is given; and the same tag is assigned to this feature's automated test case. Doing so will allow us to look for a missing tag by a tool.

Does anyone have experience in this tagging practice? Any tools to recommend?

Our automated test framework is built with Karma, Jasmine and Mocha.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend looking at [ZAPI](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211674/zapi?hosting=server&tab=overview) along with [Zephyr for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1014681/zephyr-for-jira-test-management?hosting=cloud&tab=overview).

This is a standard requirement and I think this also can be easily achieved by [creating and adding a tag to a test case as a 'custom Field' in Jira](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-questions/Tagging-a-test-case-Automated/qaq-p/221074).